# Package not linking - error: package com.beefe.picker does not exist import com.beefe.picker.PickerViewPackage;

Tags: react-native

I have tried running npm install react-native-picker --save
                                 react-native-link
etc but the package remains missing every time I run react-native run-android

https://github.com/beefe/react-native-picker/issues/67

Nothing I tried from this list works.  I would like suggestions on debugging this type of react-native error. The node_module is there. What else could be keeping it from being visible during react-native run-android?  Is this a failure to link? Is it a failure to compile? How do I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solution is work around wrong version of Android compile and target at 27. Work around is to go into node_modules of picker and modify android.gradle under app to switch 27 to 28 for target etc. That fixes it.